# C# - How to add user claims/roles from JWT on Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-identity

I am trying to setup client authorization in my application. My final objective is to make an HTTP request to an API that will return a list of claims for given user. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to add claims to the Claims Identity.

Here's what I am trying in the `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimsIdentity);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
[Authorize(Roles = ("Admin"))]
public IHttpActionResult GetClaims()
{
    return Ok("Success");
}
```

And finally this is the response `401 - Unauthorized`:

```
{
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are supposed to add claims to the token when creating the token, so please share the part of the code that generates the token.

Comment: @rad That is irrelevant right now. I would like to start with at least adding a manual Role and being able to authorize the user with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add identity in current principal:

```
var userNameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appID);

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { userNameClaim }, "Admin");

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

Comment: Still no luck, however if I remove the `Authorize` tag from the controller I am able to see the claim in the Principal.Identity but it still returns unauthorized.

Comment: can you debug and check whether the "Admin" role is properly getting added in the current principal or not?